# How to combine NER with sentiment when fine-tuning BERT

Tags: python, natural-language

I'd like to fine-tune Google's BERT model for entity-level sentiment, similar to Google's Natural Language API ([demo](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language#section-2)). I'm using a sample fine-tuning Colab implementation found [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/NielsRogge/Transformers-Tutorials/blob/master/BERT/Custom_Named_Entity_Recognition_with_BERT_only_first_wordpiece.ipynb#scrollTo=wPYV2Ld6Tr5I). My current approach is to fine-tune BERT for span detection along with its property by creating tag subclasses with labelled sentiments. Here's the first sentence:

```
|    | Sentence #   | Word          | POS   | Tag   |
|---:|:-------------|:--------------|:------|:------|
|  0 | Sentence: 1  | Thousands     | NNS   | O     |
|  1 | nan          | of            | IN    | O     |
|  2 | nan          | demonstrators | NNS   | O     |
|  3 | nan          | have          | VBP   | O     |
|  4 | nan          | marched       | VBN   | O     |
|  5 | nan          | through       | IN    | O     |
|  6 | nan          | London        | NNP   | B-geo |
|  7 | nan          | to            | TO    | O     |
|  8 | nan          | protest       | VB    | O     |
|  9 | nan          | the           | DT    | O     |
| 10 | nan          | war           | NN    | O     |
| 11 | nan          | in            | IN    | O     |
| 12 | nan          | Iraq          | NNP   | B-geo |
| 13 | nan          | and           | CC    | O     |
| 14 | nan          | demand        | VB    | O     |
| 15 | nan          | the           | DT    | O     |
| 16 | nan          | withdrawal    | NN    | O     |
| 17 | nan          | of            | IN    | O     |
| 18 | nan          | British       | JJ    | B-gpe |
| 19 | nan          | troops        | NNS   | O     |
| 20 | nan          | from          | IN    | O     |
| 21 | nan          | that          | DT    | O     |
| 22 | nan          | country       | NN    | O     |
| 23 | nan          | .             | .     | O     |
```

Where `B-geo` for `London` would be -0.3, Iraq -0.1, and British 0.0, where -0.3, -0.1, and 0.0 are arbitrary sentiment values that I assigned. Would appending these sentiment values to `Tag` be the right approach?

The only related question I could find was [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68794/sentiment-analysis-with-respect-to-subject), asked 8+ years ago.

Comment: And what is exactly your question? What you say you do sounds right to me. Is there any issue?

Comment: @Jindřich my more specific question: is this in line with NLP best practices? And are there alternative approaches? One potential problem is that it becomes difficult to balance the classifications. For example, there more tags closer to neutral (0) than extreme (+/- 1)